# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 49

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the code it consists of signIn function in PHP session:

```
function SignIn(){

    session_start(); 

    //starting the session for user profile page if(!empty($_POST['User'])) 

    //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text 
    { 

        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM User where User = 'UserName' AND pass = 'Password'")or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error()); 

        if(!empty($row['User']) AND !empty($row['Pass'])) 
        {
            $_SESSION['User'] = $row['Pass'];
            echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
        } 

        else 
        { 
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; 
        } 
    } 
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    SignIn();
```

Giving error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 49

Comment: see if the query is being formed correctly. echo the query to the browser. There could also be an issue with the connection

Answer (score 1):

You don't have

```
$connection = mysqli_connect();
```

You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`:

```
... or die(mysql_error());
```

Signature of `mysqli_query`:

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

You only have 1 param, the query. Should be:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ....");
```